# Equivalent for ? in Java for Python?

Tags: java, python

In java, I use the

```
variable = something == 1 ? 1 : 0
```

function all the time. Is there an equivalent function in python?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Python, that operator reads slightly differently - more like English. The equivalent to your Java statement in Python would be:

```
variable = 1 if something == 1 else 0
```

Answer (score 3):

It is called the 'conditional' in Python:

```
>>> 'one' if 1 else 'not'
'one'
```

Covered in [PEP308](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0308/)